# LINQ: Converting grouped list into new list

Tags: c#, list, linq, visual-studio-2008, group-by

Initially I have a list of items:

```
List<Item> mySourceList;
```

which Item is:

**Item Class**:

```
public class Item
{
   public DateTime Date
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
   public string ProviderID
   {
     get;
     set;
   }    
   public List<AnotherClass> listOfitems
   {
     get;       
     set;
   }
   public byte[] Img
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
   // Other properties

   public long GroupID
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

I need to group mySourceList by ProviderID and Date so I do below:

```
var grp = mySourceList .GroupBy(e => new { e.ProviderID, e.Date });
```

Then I perform some opertions in this grouped list:

```
int groupId = 1;
foreach (var group in grp)
{
    int id = group.Count() > 1 ? groupId++ : 0;

    // Loop through each item within group
    foreach (var item in group)
        item.GroupID = id;
}
```

And Finally, I am trying to convert mySourceList  list into a new one, this new one must be List again, so I am trying below but it is not working:

```
List<Item> myDestList = grp.ToList<Item>();
```

How can I convert to List ?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` extension method.
`grp` is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<'a, Item>>` - so it some kind of list of list.
And you need return flattened list of all items.

```
List<Item> myDestList = grp.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Another approach is using your original list, because your code updating already existed items.

Comment: Finally I have token advantage of the loops, see my answer. Anyway, your solution works perfectly and I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done below by taking advantage of the operation to update grouped list in the loops:

```
List<Item> groupedList = new List<Item>();

int groupId = 1;
foreach (var group in grp)
{
    int id = group.Count() > 1 ? groupId++ : 0;

    // Loop through each item within group
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        item.GroupID = id;
        groupedList.add(Item);
    }
}

myDestList = groupedList;
```

Fabio solution also works.